# Derivation of poisson kernel for disk of radius $R$ from unit disk

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Is there a way to derive poisson kernel for disk of radius $R$ from unit disk?

Comment: Checking Wikipedia is the minimum before asking : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel

Comment: I realize, and I've looked at the wiki article, but that is not what I'm asking. It is very easy to derive the Poisson integral formula for a disc or radius 1. What I'm asking is: is there are easy way to generalize to disks of arbitrary radius without starting again? I.e. going from the result on the unit disk

Comment: Ok, I've found a decent answer: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PoissonKernel.html

Comment: Actually this is not a bad question, I upvoted. It is not obvious that one can obtain the Poisson kernel for an arbitrary disk from the Poisson kernel of the unit disk. I'd say that this depends on the fact that the Laplacian has constant coefficients.

Comment: I stumbled on my seven years old previous comment (!!), and I would like to correct it. The key fact is that the Laplacian is covariant under scaling, that is, $\Delta(f(\lambda\cdot))=\lambda^2\Delta f$, for all $\lambda >0$. This, not the constant coefficient, is the property of the Laplacian that is used here.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a scaling substitution $\frac{r}{R}$ in place of $r$ for non-zero $R$ in the Poisson kernel formula for the unit disk
\begin{equation*}
P_r=\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos(\theta)+r^2}.
\end{equation*}
This gives us
\begin{equation*}
\frac{R^2-r^2}{R^2-2rR\cos(\theta) +r^2}.
\end{equation*}
Also note that via the modularity of the exponential function and Euler's identity, the denominator becomes $|Re^{it}-re^{i\theta}|^2$ by factorisation giving us an immediate upper and lower bound.

Comment: What do you mean by "modularity of the exponential function"? (I am very optimistic, I think I will obtain an answer from a deactivated user!)

Comment: Oh, I think I got it! "Modularity of the exponential function" means that $\lvert e^{i\theta}\rvert =1$. (Also, in this answer $t$ must be $0$).